# How to change embebed-tomcat default port using spring boot?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using spring-boot with maven, this is my configuration class:

```
package hello;

import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When the app starts show this line in console:

```
2014-11-06 17:00:55.102  INFO 4669 --- [main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080/http
```

I want to change the TomcatEmbedded port to 8081 for the case.
Thanks :D

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Set the value via the `server.port` property, just like explained [in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port), e.g.:

> mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments='-Dserver.port=8081'

Comment: in my scenario, this workds:
<code>mvn exec:java -Dserver.port=8081</code>

Answer (score 7):

There are 3-4 ways to change it. Add application.properties under

```
src/main/resources/
```

and add the property as below to the file:

```
server.port = 8084
```

For other ways to change, go through [this link](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-change-tomcat-port/).

Spring official documentation [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-change-the-http-port) for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use double quote:

> mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Dserver.port=8081"

Comment: Single quotes work just as well - otherwise this is an exact duplicate of the long-accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

Write this in application.yml:

```
server:
  port: [your port]
```

for example

```
server:
  port:8888
```

to change the default port to 8888